Ambiguity in defining an equivalence relation over a free vector space
In the context of proposing different constructions of tensor, my professor defined the following equivalence relation on the free vector space over $V \times W$ with pointwise addition and pointwise scalar multiplication
$$\mathbb{R}^{(V \times W)}:= \{f:V\times W\rightarrow \mathbb{R}: |f^{-1}(\mathbb{R}\backslash\{0\})|< \infty\}$$
$$e_{(v,w)} \in \mathbb{R}^{(V\times W)}... \text{the function which is $0$ everywhere and $1$ at $(v,w)$}$$
$$e_{(v_1+v_2,w)} \sim e_{(v_1,w)}+e_{(v_2,w)}$$
$$e_{(v,w_1+w_2)} \sim e_{(v,w_1)}+e_{(v,w_2)}$$
$$e_{(\lambda v,w)} \sim \lambda e_{(v,w)} \sim e_{(v,\lambda w)}$$
Supposing this equivalence relation is transitive and compatible with both addition and scalar multiplication, by that I mean
$$ a\sim b, b \sim c \Rightarrow a \sim c \\ a \sim b \Rightarrow \lambda a \sim \lambda b \\ a\sim c, b \sim d \Rightarrow a+b \sim c+d$$
Are these statements enough to fully define an equivalence relation? How would one go about checking if two random elements of the vector space are quivalent under this relation? I am guessing you would write both vectors in term of the basis ${}$, and then individually compare each possible subsum of vectors on the left with each possible subsum on the right? So for example for $e_{(1,0)}+e_{(2,0)}+e_{(3,0)} \sim 3e_{(1,0)}+e_{(2,0)}?$
$$\text{check} \ e_{(1,0)}+e_{(2,0)} \sim 3e_{(1,0)}$$
$$\text{check} \ e_{(1,0)}+e_{(2,0)} \sim e_{(2,0)}$$
$$\text{check} \ e_{(1,0)}+e_{(2,0)} \sim 3e_{(1,0)}+e_{(2,0)}$$
$$\text{check} \ e_{(1,0)}+e_{(3,0)}\sim 3e_{(1,0)}$$
.
.
. and so on till you check all possible sum combinations
I have explained my question in the context of this specific example, but my question is more general: Is it possible to define an equivalence relation by defining some elements to be in relation, and then positing that the equivalence relation is compatible with both scalar multiplication and addition?

@jd27 the cardinality of the inverse image of 0 must be finite

Not of $0$ but of its complement. Moreover, there are various conventions about $0$ belonging or not to $\Bbb N$. So, better replace $|f^-1({0})|\in \mathbb{N}$ with $|f^{-1}(\Bbb R\setminus{0})|<\infty$. Also, better write $\Bbb R^{(V\times W)}:=\dots$, which is a subset of $\Bbb R^{V\times W}$.

The equivalence relation is more clearly defined by:
$f\sim g\iff f-g\in S$, where $S$ is the linear subspace of $\Bbb R^{(V\times W)}$ spanned by all the vectors of the form:
$$\begin{align}e_{(x+y,z)} - e_{(x,z)} - e_{(y,z)}\e_{(x,y+z)} - e_{(x,y)} - e_{(x,z)}\e_{(\alpha x, y)} - \lambda e_{(x,y)}\e_{(x, \alpha y)} - \lambda e_{(x,y)}.\end{align}$$ This should answer your first question Are these statements enough to fully define an equivalence relation? But I guess your main question is about an algorithm to detect whether a given element of  $\Bbb R^{(V\times W)}$ belongs to $S$.

So, "ambiguity" in your title is a little misleading.

Oops small mistyping in my vectors above: the two $\alpha$s should be $\lambda$s.

@AnneBauval I have added your recommended changes. My question is the context of the specific example, but my question is more general. I am wondering if it is possible to define an equivalence relation by defining some elements to be in relation, and then positing that the equivalence relation is compatible with both scalar multiplication and addition?

Of course! Do exactly the same as here: take the subspace spanned by the differences of pairs of elements which you want to be related. So your question was only that, and not about some algorithm?

You say in words "compatible with addition" but when you spell out what that means in symbols you don't seem to mention it. It seems to me that you need a third statement in the paragraph starting "Supposing ... by that I mean"

@AnneBauval that was my central question, but I am interested in a concrete algorithm nonetheless.

@ancientmathematician I have added the third statement now

If you have a basis of $V$ and $W$, then $S$ is generated by the differences in my comments above for only $x,y,z$ in those two basis, and there is an obvious algorithm to reduce uniquely, mod $S$, any element of $\Bbb R^{(V\times W)}$ to a linear combination of the $e_{x,y}$ for $x,y$ in those two basis. In short: if $B,B'$ are basis for $V,W$ then $(x\otimes y)_{x\in B,y\in B'}$ is a basis of $V\otimes W$.
